# Group together identical elements in a vector using r

Tags: r

A very simple question but couldn't find an answer.

I have a vector of characters (for example - "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b").

I would like to group together the elements to "a" "c" "b".

Is there a specific function for that?

Thank you

Comment: PLease give an exampe vector and expected result. More precisely

Comment: Do you want to add the number of each element or something else ? As @dww said, provide an expected output.

Comment: assuming you want to keep the order the same as oreder of first occurence in the original vector, you could maybe use `as.character(y[order(y <- factor(x, levels = unique(x)))])`. Or just `y[order(y <- factor(x, levels = unique(x)))]` if a factor result is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `sqldf` librayr and using `group by`:

```
require(sqldf)    

vector<- data.frame(v=c("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b"))
sqldf("SELECT v from vector group by v")
```

Comment: Thanks but I looking to group together different sectors in the vector, i.e. to take ("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b"), and to get: ("a", "c", "b", "a", "c", "b").

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
vector <- c("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b")
sorted <- sort(vector)
```

Comment: Thanks but I looking to group together different sectors in the vector, i.e. to take ("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b"), and to get: ("a", "c", "b", "a", "c", "b").

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the unique elements then there is, well, `unique`.

```
> unique(c("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b"), sort=TRUE)
[1] "a" "c" "b"
```

**Update**

With the new description of the problem, this would be my solution

```
shifted <- c(NA, vector[-length(vector)])
vector[is.na(shifted) | vector != shifted]
```

I shift the vector one to the right, putting `NA` at the front because I have no better idea of what to put there, and then pick out the elements that are not `NA` and not equal to the previous element.

If the vector contains `NA`, some additional checks will be needed. It is not obvious how to put something that isn't the first element in the first position of the shifted vector without knowing a bit more. For example, you could extract all the elements form the vector and pick one that isn't the first, but that would fail if the vector only contains identical elements.

Another question now: is there a smarter way to implement the `shift` operation? I couldn't think of one, but there might be an more canonical solution.

Comment: Well, thanks for the downvote -- I guess `unique` wasn't what you were looking for...

Comment: Thanks but I looking to group together different sectors in the vector, i.e. to take ("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b"), and to get: ("a", "c", "b", "a", "c", "b").